# I would like to create a column conditional if else statement to return the heading of the column value it evaluates

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, nested

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['1010', 'X', 'X', "", "", "", ""], ['1515', 'X','X','X',"", "", ""], ['2020', "",  "", "", "", "", '85%']]


df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['ID', '25%','50%', '75%', '90%','100%','Other' ])
```

This spreadsheet tracks production progress, but I would like to get this number from a single column with a percentage value instead of the X marking the heading for its percentage.

```
def digit(row):
    if ((row['25%'] == "X")and(row['50%'==""])):
        val = '25%'
    elif ((row['50%'] == "X")and(row['75%']=="")): 
        val = '50%' 
    elif ((row['75%'] == "X")and(row['90%']=="")):  
        val = '75%'  
    elif ((row['90%'] == "X")and(row['100%']=="")):
        val = '90%'  
    elif row['100%'] == "X":
        val = '100%'
    elif row ['Other'] !="":
        val = 'Other'
    return val 

df['Percent'] = df.apply(digit, axis = 1)
```

My code yields 25% for the firts two and prints 'Other' for the last one. Which is not bad but would be better if I could print the value in that column instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `idxmax`:

```
df['Percent'] = df.iloc[:,:0:-1].ne('').idxmax(1)

# update `Percent` where `Other` is not empty
df['Percent'] = df['Percent'].mask(df['Other'].ne(''), df['Other'])
```

Output:

```
     ID 25% 50% 75% 90% 100% Other Percent
0  1010   X   X                        50%
1  1515   X   X   X                    75%
2  2020                        85%     85%
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible. Just access that value:

```
elif row ['Other'] !="":
    val = row['Other']
```

---

You probably have a typo here:

```
elif row['100%'] == "X":
    val = '90%'            <---
```